# Htmlservice using transform:rotate does not pass caja?

Tags: css, google-apps-script, google-caja

I have a script *doGet* where I use the `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile` service to render a html file.

In the html I use a stylesheet as follows

```
 .title {
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border: 20px solid #404BBD ;
  font-size:90px;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(30deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg)
  }
```

Which I apply to a div tag in the body of the html. Most of the Css is applied though the rotation of the DIV does not seem to happen. 
`<div class="title">Hello</div>`

Am I doing something wrong or does [Google Caja](http://caja.appspot.com/) not accept the rotation for real?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caja does not whitelist the `transform` property. Please feel free to [request it be added](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/entry).

Comment: Thnks @Kevin Reid, just added the [request](https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/issues/detail?id=1701)!